# Sort list of objects on one of the object's Properties

Tags: c#, .net, list, sortedlist

I have a list of objects `List<MyObject>` and I want to have this list sorted based on one of the properties of `MyObject`. So, for example

```
MyObject obj1, obj2, obj3 = new MyObject();
obj1.Value = 0.2;
obj2.Value = 2.2;
obj3.Value = 1.3;
```

..the order of the List<> would be

```
List[0] = obj2;
List[1] = obj3;
List[2] = obj1;
```

Can I do this using .NET native functions or must I write my own search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 Option [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
yourList = yourList.OrderBy(x=>x.PropertyName).ToList();
```

descending

```
yourList = yourList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.PropertyName).ToList();
```

2 Option [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
yourList.Sort((x,y)=>x.PropertyName.CompareTo(y.PropertyName));
```

descending

```
yourList.Sort((x,y)=>-x.PropertyName.CompareTo(y.PropertyName));
```

Comment: what he want it's a descending order

Answer (score 2):

Use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(v => v.Value).ToList();
```

There's also [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you  should define an `array` for your objects first and try this

```
 MyObject[] myObjList = new MyObject[]{obj1,Obj2,Obj3};   
    var myRes =myObjList.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.Value);
```